# The Voodoo XP error you cant fix . RDP / MSTSC.exe - cannot find <LANG_NAME>\mstsc.exe.MUI

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, environment-variables, path, regedit

I keep  getting the error

```
cannot file C:\Windows\System32\<LANG_NAME>\mstsc.exe.MUI
```

I do have this path

```
 C:\Windows\System32\US_en
```

and this one too

```
C:\Windows\System32\en
```

and I made sure the mstsc* files are there in each of these folders
I look up regedit to see if it helps
--is mstsc.exe.MUI wrongly referred in path . Nope
-- is LANG_NAME variable referred . Nope

reinstalled  RDP 7  via WindowsXP-KB969084-x86-enu.exe . Several times

MSTSC does not have a command line switch that will help override the path of mstsc.exe.mui
 and other other  mstsc* file needed.

I looked up all the antics  carried out to solve the problem including reseting IE settings to default. NOPE - nothing worked.

I think its not able to make sense of LANG_NAME. I created this as system variable and also included path to the mstsc* files into PATH. Still no idea
I only found this value in regedit and it seems its correctly valued

```
MUIVerb @C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\mstsc.exe.mui,-4002
```

to me it looks like  does not come from path logic or regedit but from mstsc itself...but how and where it is looking for lang_name

Comment: I suggest using ProcessMonitor and looking up at the process what exactly it is trying to load. An easy way to do this is start MSTSC under WinDbg (so it breaks on start), start ProcessMonitor, filter for the proper process ID, press g in WinDbg and watch ProcessMonitor to see what the process is trying to read :)

Comment: Its a process if it runs !. This error wont let it run , period

Comment: If you open it under debugger (WinDbg) as I mentioned above, the process will start and break immediately. This will allow you to turn ProcessMonitor and monitor the process (the process does exist). Alternatively, you can use ProcessMonitor and filter by process name for mstsc.exe